# Auto complete Data List dropdown shows again after selecting the value

Tags: angular6, datalist

[image]

I have used datalist for autocomplete values. When I type "T" I get list of values associated with "T". After selecting the specify value from the list, It shows again as below

[image]

Below is the code is used to bind the values to datalist dropdown

```
<input class="form-control" (keyup)='getLocationDetails()' 
name="location" placeholder="Ship From..." type="text" list="list" 
[(ngModel)]="shipModel.shipfrom" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
(ngModelChange)='onChangeList($event)' autocomplete="off"> <datalist id="list"> 
<option *ngFor="let obj of locationlist" [value]="obj.locname"></option></datalist>
```

How to fix this

Comment: Why is your `autocomplete="off"` property set to off?

Comment: @JefferinJoseph to disable autofill